# Jenkins: build fixed notification

Tags: notifications, jenkins

I got an email with "Build # - fixed!". So does it mean that after failures the build was finally successfully built? Am I right? I am really new in Jenkins/ Hudson :(

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the default behaviour for Jenkins; it will email you for every build failure, but will only email about a successful build if it was preceded by a failed build.  See the doc for the [Extended Email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), which is what most sites use.